# Where does the MongoDB golang driver InsertOne time come from?

Tags: mongodb, go

I use this code to get the client for mongodb:

```
package connectors

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func GetMongoDBConnection() *mongo.Client {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGODB_URI")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return client

}
```

And im using it like this, to get the connection and insert one document into the db:

```
dbClient := connectors.GetMongoDBConnection()
coll := dbClient.Database("test").Collection("test")
coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"key": "value"})
```

I tried to measure the time by doing:

```
ConnectionTime := time.Now()

dbClient := connectors.GetMongoDBConnection()

fmt.Println(time.Since(ConnectionTime).Milliseconds())

CollSelectionTime := time.Now()

coll := dbClient.Database("test").Collection("test")

fmt.Println(time.Since(CollSelectionTime).Milliseconds())

InsetionTime := time.Now()

coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"type": "congelada", "type2": "Masalado"})

fmt.Println(time.Since(InsetionTime).Milliseconds())
```

The console prints:

0

0

629

So that 629 milliseconds are from the "InsertOne"... But I don't understand why because I tried to insert 10,000 documents and it took like 2000 milliseconds, so I actually don't undestand where that ~600 milliseconds came from...

How can I reduce that time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection, DB selection, or collection selection simply capture the arguments but do not perform any actual operation. Those are used when you make the actual database operation. Thus, the first call to `InsertOne` will connect if not already connected, and perform the operation.

After connecting, call `Ping`, and that will actually connect to the DB.

Comment: oh, so as far as I undestand, the function GetMongoDBConnection, doesn't actually connect to the db until an operation is performed. I tried what you said and called .Ping() an then the operation insert one takes 0~2ms, thank you so much for responding my question!